# Problem about setting IOTTYBaseName in USBSerialDriverKit

Tags: driverkit

I want know how to set IOTTYBaseName in USBSerialDriverKit.I try to use SetProperties method  inherit from IOService like following code, but the methodreturn -301 error code.

```
    super::CopyProperties(&pDict);
    bResult = OSDictionarySetValue(pDict, kIOTTYBaseNameKey, tty_name);
    if(bResult) {
        PL_OSLOG("SET TRUE");
    } else {
        PL_OSLOG("SET FALSE");
    }
    result = super::SetProperties(pDict);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjFFo.png)